# How to listen for any 301/302 redirect status codes on cross-domain image requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a few `<img>`'s that are linked (with the `src` attribute) to cross-domain URLS that may need to redirect to some other image URL. I need to somehow track every redirect that takes place when the browser requests the original URL.

So for example, If I have:

`<img src='http://www.something.com/redirect'/>`

and `http://www.something.com/redirect` sent a custom `location` header to `http://something.com/pic.jpg`, I need to know about it. How could I detect a redirect in JS or jQuery on a `<img>`?

Comment: You can't do this with ordinary javascript. You'll need an extension or plugin. (It's probably possible with a userscript, but I don't feel like checking right now).  What is the real purpose of this exercise? (The means may be unworkable, but the madness might yet be achieved.)

Comment: Without server - impossible. With server - trivial. Take your pick :P

Comment: That's just it @Esailija, I can't use server side scripts to do the requests. I need them done on the clients machine, using the clients IP and cookies. Why? Because some of the URLS may be linked to a site that requires specific cookies set that will be sitting on the clients machine. And I obviously can't fetch those cookies from the client when they belong to a different domain (which I also have no control over). If only cross-domain `AJAX`ing was allowed. What a shame.

Comment: You can do cross-domain AJAX from a userscript, or a plugin, or an extension (add-on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not constrained to IE7 you could use a cors solution.  That will let you request cross-domain without the limitations of JSON-P (i.e. you can get status codes).

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control for more information.  For a simple GET request you should be fine, but if you need to POST then you may need to preflight your request.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's quite possible (of course I'm not an expert, but that's AFAIK), at least not as straight forward as one might think.

Here's what I think is as close as you can get to what you're looking for, I hope it gives you some ideas

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
$('img').each(function() {
    req.open('GET', $(this).prop('src'), false);
    req.send(null);
    alert(req.status);
});
```

Two down sides:

1. Only for images on the same domain.
2. You have to request the images two times (or you can do the requests first, then use the results to show the images)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<img id='img' src='' width='200' />
<script type='text/javascript'>

/* our image */
var image =  new Image();
$(image).load('yourimage.png', function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        // image loaded, now display the image
        $('#img').attr('src','yourimage.png')
    } else {
        alert(xhr.status);
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Couldn't you move the image fetching code server side (so your img src would become http://example.com/imagefetch.php?url=http://www.something.com/redirect and your imagefetch.php page would use something like cURL to fetch the remote image and keep track of the redirects (no idea by the way if cURL can do that, but you get the idea).  There are a lot of performance reasons why this is a bad idea, but if you had to accomplish it, this could work

Comment: I don't really want to use server side for this simple but nearly impossible task. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: javascript doesn't allow cross domain for good reasons - see XSS for issues it would cause. you can use flash if you want to do this client side, otherwise it is javascript for loading same domain images or perhaps serverside  as Jason suggested using sockets, curl, readfile or fopen (if it is enabled on your server).

Answer (score 0):

How about using Ajax to load the image, untested pseudo code following:

HTML:

```
<img id="img1" src="blank.gif">
```

JQuery:

```
GetImage("http://www.something.com/redirect");

function GetImage(url)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            if (data.redirect) {
                // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
                ProcessLocationHeader(data);
                GetImage(data.redirect);
            }
            else {
                // No redirect means we have the correct image
                $("#img1").src = url;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Since the browser will cache the image it won't be loaded from the server twize.